# How to get the display value of a ListView cell in C#

Tags: c#, listview

[listView1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqQjv.png)

I need to know if there is a way to get a certain item from column2 into a string as text value.

My idea was to type the name of one of the students in `textBox1` and by hitting  `Button1` it will get the right age of the student name typed in `textBox1` and place it into `textBox2` or in a `string`.

I'm using a `listview` in C#
                             [Picture as example]

Comment: Please provide more information, How you are populating the ListView? What you have done so far

Comment: What you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

```
public class PersonRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AgeText { get; set; }
    public int Age {get;set;} // ideally you wanna use integer to store person's age
}

public IEnumerable<string> GetAgeValue(string searchName)
{
    var records = new List<PersonRecord>()
    {
       new PersonRecord {Name="David", AgeText="22 years old", Age = 22 },
       new PersonRecord {Name="Sarah", AgeText="23 years old", Age = 23 },
       new PersonRecord {Name="Jane", AgeText="24 years old", Age = 24 },
    };
    // assume it follows the strict format, "[age] years old", so we will get the age value based on the first occurrence of the white space
    var result = records.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(searchName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(x => x.AgeText.Substring(0, x.AgeText.IndexOf(" ") + 1));
    // alternatively just do a query on the age directly, much easier
    // var result = records.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(searchName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Select(x => x.Age.ToString()); 
    return result;
}
```

Anyway, above is just a quick code sample for getting person's age and hopefully it will get you started.